# Trouble understanding libstdc++'s Red-black tree iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iteration, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement iterators for a [Ternary Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree), and because TSTs are very similar to BSTs, I thought I'd look at `libstdc++`'s implementation for said iterators. The idea is to iterate through all tree nodes without modifying the tree or saving anything aside from the current tree node in the iterators. The tree nodes have a parent pointer to allow this kind of iteration.

Here's the code from the latest GCC, taken from the [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/tree.cc):

```
static _Rb_tree_node_base*
local_Rb_tree_increment(_Rb_tree_node_base* __x) throw ()
{
  if (__x->_M_right != 0)
    {
      __x = __x->_M_right;
      while (__x->_M_left != 0)
        __x = __x->_M_left;
    }
  else
    {
      _Rb_tree_node_base* __y = __x->_M_parent;
      while (__x == __y->_M_right)
        {
          __x = __y;
          __y = __y->_M_parent;
        }
      if (__x->_M_right != __y)
        __x = __y;
    }
  return __x;
}
```

It looks fairly straightforward, the increment operation either takes you to your right child and then all the way to left, or to your first non-right parent. What I don't understand is the second `if` clause:

```
if (__x->_M_right != __y)
  __x = __y;
```

How could this condition ever evaluate to `false`? `__x` needs to surpass `__y` for this happen, and that does not seem possible looking at the `while` loop. I think it might be `false` if the tree were a [threaded tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree), but the `nullptr` checks at the first `if` clause seem to suggest otherwise. Also, removing the `if` clause and just writing `__x = __y;` in my code does not seem to break anything.

What is going on here?

**Edit**:

This is the code for Clang's `libc++`. It seems as though the same code is not guarded by an `if` this time:

```
 template <class _EndNodePtr, class _NodePtr>
 inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
 _EndNodePtr
 __tree_next_iter(_NodePtr __x) _NOEXCEPT
 {
     if (__x->__right_ != nullptr)
         return static_cast<_EndNodePtr>(__tree_min(__x->__right_));
     while (!__tree_is_left_child(__x))
         __x = __x->__parent_unsafe();
     return static_cast<_EndNodePtr>(__x->__parent_);
 }
```

I doubt the if is redundant as it has been there for at least two decades (since the SGI days).

Comment: If that doesn't change anything and the according test suite still runs, you might have found a way to improve the code. Go file a pull request!

Comment: Have you checked how the value of `M_parent` is set in the top node?

Comment: @4386427 It would take a pretty weird one-past-end terminator object for this if to be useful. I think it's pretty evident that leaves are zero-pointers and root's parent cannot be. Though this doesn't help constructing a case where `__x->_M_right == __x->_M_parent` and the assignment would be erroneous. It certainly is easy to create such terminator, that it doesn't need it. Unless I am heavily wrong about something. Probably the best way is to step through it with debugger on corner cases, like one element tree, incrementing last iterator, and simply check it.

Comment: @luk32 Without knowing how the tree is constructed it makes no sense to look at the iterator. The key is to understand how the members of each node is handled. I'm sure the code in question is there for a good reason but I haven't had time to look into this yet.

Comment: @4386427 Well, I beg to differ, it was a fun brain exercise to try to come up with a fitting data structure. Surely not most optimal strategy time wise =]. I was convinced the code is there for a substantial reason, but I couldn't come up with a use case. I agree it's best to see how it actually works, however the iterator itself does contain bits of information on the structure so IMHO it wasn't completely pointless to look at it.

Comment: Perhaps the root node's parent pointer is not set to null, but to a sentinel node. The sentinel node's left and right children might both be set to the root node; but the sentinel node's parent might be null.

Answer (score 1):

[EASTL](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL) uses a similar [`eastl::RBTreeIncrement`](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/source/red_black_tree.cpp#L44) based on the HP STL tree functions:

```
/// RBTreeIncrement
/// Returns the next item in a sorted red-black tree.
///
EASTL_API rbtree_node_base* RBTreeIncrement(const rbtree_node_base* pNode)
{
    if(pNode->mpNodeRight) 
    {
        pNode = pNode->mpNodeRight;

        while(pNode->mpNodeLeft)
            pNode = pNode->mpNodeLeft;
    }
    else 
    {
        rbtree_node_base* pNodeTemp = pNode->mpNodeParent;

        while(pNode == pNodeTemp->mpNodeRight) 
        {
            pNode = pNodeTemp;
            pNodeTemp = pNodeTemp->mpNodeParent;
        }

        if(pNode->mpNodeRight != pNodeTemp)
            pNode = pNodeTemp;
    }

    return const_cast<rbtree_node_base*>(pNode);
}
```

Here, the goal of the

```
while(pNode == pNodeTemp->mpNodeRight) 
{
    pNode = pNodeTemp;
    pNodeTemp = pNodeTemp->mpNodeParent;
}
    
if(pNode->mpNodeRight != pNodeTemp)
    pNode = pNodeTemp;
```

is to obtain the root node of the smallest subtree containing the current node, `pNode`, in its left branch, or the **sentinel node** if such subtree does not exist.

Graph/node-like containers (*e.g., doubly linked list, red-black tree, etc.*) use sentinel nodes for implementing `(c)end` member methods in such a way that `end() - 1` has correct semantics, and furthermore exploit them to remove edge cases (or move the edge cases from one algorithm to another).

EASTL defines its sentinel, `mAnchor`, in its [`eastl::rbtree`](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/internal/red_black_tree.h#L348) as follows:

> We do the conventional trick of assigning begin() (left-most rbtree node) to mpNodeLeft, assigning 'end() - 1' (a.k.a. rbegin()) to mpNodeRight, and assigning the tree root node to mpNodeParent.

E.g., if there is only one node in the red-black tree the left child, right child and parent node of the sentinel node will all point to that single node.

This means that for **incrementing the root node without a right child node**, we will take the else branch in [`eastl::RBTreeIncrement`](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/source/red_black_tree.cpp#L44) and end up with `pNode` being equal to the sentinel node after the while-loop, which is the intended result of the increment. The condition of the following `if` statement will be `false` because `pNodeTemp` will be equal to the parent of the sentinel node which is the root node itself, while `pNode->mpNodeRight` will be equal to the right child of the sentinel node which is the root node as well.